# Fn + left arrow shortcut activates screen settings

Tags: 15.10, screen, xfce, brightness, shortcuts

I'm running Ubuntu studio 15.10 (xfce). I have problem with keyboard shortcut for decreasing screen brightness <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd>. It is working but additionally it activates screen settings. How can I disable this shortcut form activating screen settings? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Keyboard > Application Shortcuts I have `xfce4-display-settings --minimal` listed in a couple of places. You may want to try deleting or re-assigning those. Sometimes you cannot delete particular entries for keyboard shortcuts for applications. I know this is the case for some in Window Manager > Keyboard. In order to assign the same shortcut to something else they must be re-assigned to a different shortcut. You can always pick something random or obscure for that.

You may also want to run the following to see what comes up. You may need to manually delete an entry in this file. For those changes to activate, you'll need to log out and log in again.

```
grep -i display ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thank you jbrock. :)

Comment: I'm glad that worked! :) Just out of curiosity, were you able to delete the keyboard assignment or did you need to re-assign it? I'd be sure to log in and out again to ensure the changes keep.

Comment: I was able to delete the keyboard assignment. Once again thanks for your help :)!